# Python click 'More' button is not working

Tags: python, selenium, button, click

I tried to click "More" button for each review so that I can expand these text reviews to the full contents and then I try to scrape those text reviews. Without clicking "More" button, what I end up retrieving is something like 

"This room was nice and clean. The location...More".

I tried a few different functions to figure it out such as selenium button click and ActionChain but I guess I'm not using these properly. Could someone help me out with this issue?

Below is my current code:
I didn't upload the whole code to avoid some unnecessary outputs (tried to make it simple).

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver import ActionChains

#Incognito Mode
option=webdriver.ChromeOptions()
option.add_argument("--incognito")

#Open Chrome
driver=webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="C:/Users/chromedriver.exe",chrome_options=option)

#url I want to visit.
lists=['https://www.tripadvisor.com/VacationRentalReview-g30196-d6386734-Hot_51st_St_Walk_to_Mueller_2BDR_Modern_sleeps_7-Austin_Texas.html']

for k in lists:

    driver.get(k)
    html =driver.page_source
    soup=BeautifulSoup(html,"html.parser")
    time.sleep(3)
    listing=soup.find_all("div", class_="review-container")

    for i in range(len(listing)):

        try:
            #First, I tried this but didn't work.
            #link = driver.find_element_by_link_text('More')
            #driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", link)

            #Second, I tried ActionaChains but didn't work.
            ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(i).click().perform()
        except:
            pass

        text_review=soup.find_all("div", class_="prw_rup prw_reviews_text_summary_hsx")
        text_review_inside=text_review[i].find("p", class_="partial_entry")
        review_text=text_review_inside.text

        print (review_text)
```

Comment: you the biggest mistake in all this code is `except: pass`. Without this you would resolve problem long time ago. Code raise error message with all information but you can't see it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your the biggest mistake in all this code is `except: pass.` Without this you would resolve problem long time ago. Code raise error message with all information but you can't see it. You could at least use

```
except Exception as ex:
    print(ex)
```

---

Problem is that `move_to_element()` will not work with `BeautifulSoup` elements. I has to be Selenium's element - like

```
link = driver.find_element_by_link_text('More')

ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(link)
```

But after executing some functions Selenium needs some time to do it - and Python has to wait awaile.

I don't use `BeautifulSoup` to get data but if you want to use it then get `driver.page_source` after clicking all links. Or you will have to get again and again `driver.page_source` after every click.

Sometimes after clicking you may have to get again even Selenium elements - so I first get entry to click `More` and later I get `partial_entry` to get reviews.

I found that clicking `More` in first review it shows text for all reviews so it doesn't need to click on all `More`.

Tested with Firefox 69, Linux Mint 19.2, Python 3.7.5, Selenium 3.141

---

```
#from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver import ActionChains
import time

#Incognito Mode
option = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
option.add_argument("--incognito")

#Open Chrome
#driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="C:/Users/chromedriver.exe",chrome_options=option)

driver = webdriver.Firefox()

#url I want to visit.
lists = ['https://www.tripadvisor.com/VacationRentalReview-g30196-d6386734-Hot_51st_St_Walk_to_Mueller_2BDR_Modern_sleeps_7-Austin_Texas.html']

for url in lists:

    driver.get(url)
    time.sleep(3)

    link = driver.find_element_by_link_text('More')

    try:
        ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(link)
        time.sleep(1) # time to move to link

        link.click()
        time.sleep(1) # time to update HTML
    except Exception as ex:
        print(ex)

    description = driver.find_element_by_class_name('vr-overview-Overview__propertyDescription--1lhgd')
    print('--- description ---')
    print(description.text)
    print('--- end ---')

    # first "More" shows text in all reviews - there is no need to search other "More"
    first_entry = driver.find_element_by_class_name('entry')
    more = first_entry.find_element_by_tag_name('span')

    try:
        ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(more)
        time.sleep(1) # time to move to link

        more.click()
        time.sleep(1) # time to update HTML
    except Exception as ex:
        print(ex)

    all_reviews = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('partial_entry')
    print('all_reviews:', len(all_reviews))

    for i, review in enumerate(all_reviews, 1):
        print('--- review', i, '---')
        print(review.text)
        print('--- end ---')
```

---

**EDIT:**

To skip responses I search all `class="wrap"` and then inside every wrap I search `class="partial_entry"`. I every wrap can be only one review and eventually one response. Review has alwasy index `[0]`. Some wraps don't keep review so they will gives empty list - and I have to check it before I can get element `[0]` from list.

```
all_reviews = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('wrap')
#print('all_reviews:', len(all_reviews))

for review in all_reviews:
    all_entries = review.find_elements_by_class_name('partial_entry')
    if all_entries:
        print('--- review ---')
        print(all_entries[0].text)
        print('--- end ---')
```

Comment: Hi, I appreciate your revised comments. But it looks like that I'm also retrieving managerial response (host's comments for reviews) at the same time. text reviews and managerial response have same div class, that's why. Is there any way not to collect managerial response?

Comment: there are other functions to search element and you can create more complex rules or functions. You can even use `XPath`. In every class="wrap" is only one review and one managerial response - if you first find all "wrap" and inside every "wrap" you search review then first will be your review - `all_reviews_in_wrap[0]`

Comment: Hi, is there any reason why action chain does not work on the 2nd page of reviews for that listing? 'more' button is not clickable for the 2nd page of the reviews.