# python3 More button clickable in the 1st page but NOT clickable in the 2nd page

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, web-scraping

This is the extended question on how to click 'More' button on a webpage.
Below is my previous question and one person kindly answered for it.
Since I'm not that familiar with 'find element by class name' function, I just added that person's revised code on my existing code. So my revised code would not be efficient (my apology).

[Python click 'More' button is not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58550908/python-click-more-button-is-not-working/58551513#58551513)

The situation is, there are two types of 'More' button. 1st one is in the property description part and the 2nd one is in the text reviews part. If you click only one 'More' button from any of the reviews, reviews will be expanded so that you can see the full text reviews.

The issue I run into is that I can click 'More' button for the reviews that are in the 1st page but not clickable for the reviews in the 2nd page. 
Below is the error message I get but my code still runs (without stopping once it sees an error).
Message:

> no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"tag name","selector":"span"}

Based on my understanding, there is entry class and corresponding span for every review. I don't understand why it says python can't find it.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver import ActionChains
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

review_list=[]
review_appended_list=[]
review_list_v2=[]
review_appended_list_v2=[]
listed_reviews=[]
listed_reviews_v2=[]
listed_reviews_total=[]
listed_reviews_total_v2=[]
final_list=[]

#Incognito Mode
option = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
option.add_argument("--incognito")

#Open Chrome
driver=webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="C:/Users/chromedriver.exe",options=option)

#url I want to visit (I'm going to loop over multiple listings but for simplicity, I just added one listing url).
lists = ['https://www.tripadvisor.com/VacationRentalReview-g30196-d6386734-Hot_51st_St_Walk_to_Mueller_2BDR_Modern_sleeps_7-Austin_Texas.html']

for k in lists:

    driver.get(k)
    time.sleep(3)

    #click 'More' on description part.
    link = driver.find_element_by_link_text('More')

    try:
        ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(link)
        time.sleep(1) # time to move to link

        link.click()
        time.sleep(1) # time to update HTML
    except Exception as ex:
        print(ex)

    time.sleep(3)

    # first "More" shows text in all reviews - there is no need to search other "More"
    try:
        first_entry = driver.find_element_by_class_name('entry')
        more = first_entry.find_element_by_tag_name('span')
        #more = first_entry.find_element_by_link_text('More')
    except Exception as ex:
        print(ex)

    try:
        ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(more)
        time.sleep(1) # time to move to link

        more.click()
        time.sleep(1) # time to update HTML
    except Exception as ex:
        print(ex)

    #begin parsing html and scraping data.
    html =driver.page_source
    soup=BeautifulSoup(html,"html.parser")
    listing=soup.find_all("div", class_="review-container")

    all_reviews = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('wrap')
    for review in all_reviews:

        all_entries = review.find_elements_by_class_name('partial_entry')
        if all_entries:
            review_list=[all_entries[0].text]
            review_appended_list.extend([review_list])

    for i in range(len(listing)):
        review_id=listing[i]["data-reviewid"]
        listing_v1=soup.find_all("div", class_="rating reviewItemInline")
        rating=listing_v1[i].span["class"][1]
        review_date=listing_v1[i].find("span", class_="ratingDate relativeDate")
        review_date_detail=review_date["title"]

        listed_reviews=[review_id, review_date_detail, rating[7:8]]
        listed_reviews.extend([k])
        listed_reviews_total.append(listed_reviews)

    for a,b in zip (listed_reviews_total,review_appended_list):
        final_list.append(a+b)

    #loop over from the 2nd page of the reviews for the same listing.
    for j in range(5,20,5):
        url_1='-'.join(k.split('-',3)[:3])
        url_2='-'.join(k.split('-',3)[3:4])

        middle="-or%d-" % j

        final_k=url_1+middle+url_2

        driver.get(final_k)
        time.sleep(3)

        link = driver.find_element_by_link_text('More')

        try:
            ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(link)
            time.sleep(1) # time to move to link

            link.click()
            time.sleep(1) # time to update HTML
        except Exception as ex:
            print(ex)

        # first "More" shows text in all reviews - there is no need to search other "More"
        try:
            first_entry = driver.find_element_by_class_name('entry')
            more = first_entry.find_element_by_tag_name('span')
        except Exception as ex:
            print(ex)

        try:
            ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(more)
            time.sleep(2) # time to move to link

            more.click()
            time.sleep(2) # time to update HTML
        except Exception as ex:
            print(ex)

        html =driver.page_source
        soup=BeautifulSoup(html,"html.parser")
        listing=soup.find_all("div", class_="review-container")


        all_reviews = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('wrap')
        for review in all_reviews:
            all_entries = review.find_elements_by_class_name('partial_entry')
            if all_entries:
                #print('--- review ---')
                #print(all_entries[0].text)
                #print('--- end ---')
                review_list_v2=[all_entries[0].text]
                #print (review_list)
                review_appended_list_v2.extend([review_list_v2])

                #print (review_appended_list)

        for i in range(len(listing)):
            review_id=listing[i]["data-reviewid"]
            #print review_id
            listing_v1=soup.find_all("div", class_="rating reviewItemInline")
            rating=listing_v1[i].span["class"][1]
            review_date=listing_v1[i].find("span", class_="ratingDate relativeDate")
            review_date_detail=review_date["title"]
            listed_reviews_v2=[review_id, review_date_detail, rating[7:8]]
            listed_reviews_v2.extend([k])


            listed_reviews_total_v2.append(listed_reviews_v2)

        for a,b in zip (listed_reviews_total_v2,review_appended_list_v2):
            final_list.append(a+b)

        print (final_list)
        if len(listing) !=5:
            break
```

How to enable clicking 'More' button for the 2nd and rest of the pages? so that I can scrape the full text reviews?

Edited Below:

The error messages I get are these two lines.

```
Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"tag name","selector":"span"}
Message: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document
```

I guess my whole codes still run because I used try and except function? Usually when python runs into an error, it stops running.

Comment: Are you getting any errors on 2nd page for more buttons? can you post the complete stack trace ? which line of code causing this?

Comment: @Sureshmani Hi, there. Yes, you're right. I get an error on the 2nd page for more buttons for reviews! more button at the property descriptions works. I added error messages I get.

Answer (score 0):

Try it like:

```
driver.execute_script("""
  arguments[0].click()
""", link)
```

Comment: Replace link.click() with this.